# Registration of OCX file

Tags: vb.net, activex, windows-installer

I am creating an MSI Package for my application.There are some ocx files which needs to included as the part of the installer.
When i try to install this package it says

"registration of ocx failed,contact administrator personnel" with some error code,this happens with all the ocx file in the package.

i investigated the registration property of the ocx files and it is set to "vsdrfCOMSelfReg".

what might be the problem?

Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Check the dependency of the OCX file using depends.exe from where it tried to register. if any dependency is missing then the registration fails automatically.
2. Check you have admin rights